# How to export changes from a .tex file back to the source .Rnw file

Tags: sweave, knitr, latexdiff

Let's say my work-flow is writing a paper with multiple `R` chunks as a `.Rnw` then compiling it into a `.tex` file and then typesetting it into the final document.

Now, after the document has been compiled into a `TeX` file I usually like to do my edits directly in there, without going back to the source `.Rnw`. But then if at some point I need to recompile the whole `TeX` file (let's say my data has changed) I need to painstakingly check for all the differences between the texts of the two versions.

Problem is that simply comparing the two files (i.e. `M-x diff` in `Emacs`) will return too many differences to be useful.

Would it be possible to check and automatically update only the text of the `.Rnw` file excluding all the markups and chunks?

Comment: That will be difficult. I'd recommend working with the _real_ source file, i.e. .Rnw, since .tex is a derived and intermediate output file. It is not easy to go back.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but have a different solution in mind which may help you (if I can get help figuring it out): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256936/redefining-the-knitr-code-chunk-delimeter-in-latex-to-compile-rnw-files-as-tex